# Why do I get these symbols when im trying to save data in txt (java)

Tags: java, swing, file, save

**Before you think that this is to long just please try to help me out ive been on this issue all day(9:52 AM - 4:54 PM), its just bugging me.**

I cant seem to save these data correctly I have mainly doubles and strings, I am saving these in a .txt file called "autosAudi.txt", I get these weird codes and boxes and sometimes for whatever reason Chinese in my textfields? Here is a example of what appears:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/63259070@N06/6449175293

as you can see these weird boxes appear out nowhere I didnt register nothing like that, the way I navigate through the data is by clicking >> (next)  or << (previous) and the information is supposed to change, the textfield next to "Numero" is supposed to give me a way to input an int code so I can search the data(for example if I write 1, its supposed to find that registry). it only works for the number 1 and after that it gives this error:

```
run:
3-Dec-2011 5:02:01 PM rent_autos.Interfaz3 jbBucar_AMouseClicked
SEVERE: null
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readChar(RandomAccessFile.java:695)
at rent_autos.Autos.leerCadena(Autos.java:276)
at rent_autos.Autos.buscar(Autos.java:344)
at rent_autos.Interfaz3.jbBucar_AMouseClicked(Interfaz3.java:4640)
at rent_autos.Interfaz3.access$1100(Interfaz3.java:30)
at rent_autos.Interfaz3$12.mouseClicked(Interfaz3.java:745)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Here is the code that I used for saving the file in the "autosAudi.txt":

```
public void guardar() throws IOException    {
int opcion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"¿Desea guardar los                  
cambios?","Datos Persona",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);


if(opcion == 0){
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("autosAudi.txt","rw");
f.seek(f.length());
f.writeInt(codigo);
f.writeDouble(costo);
f.writeDouble(rendimientoGalon);
escribirCadena(f, ACRISS);
escribirCadena(f, color);
escribirCadena(f, modelo);
escribirCadena(f, tipoAM);
escribirCadena(f, placa);
escribirCadena(f, marca );

f.close();
}

}
```

And also used:

```
public boolean cargarDatosRegistro(long iPosicion, String sRuta){
boolean bRealizado = true;
try {
RandomAccessFile fRegistro = new RandomAccessFile(sRuta,"rw");
fRegistro.seek(iPosicion);
codigo  = fRegistro.readInt();
costo = fRegistro.readDouble();
rendimientoGalon  = fRegistro.readDouble();
ACRISS  = leerCadena(fRegistro);
color  = leerCadena(fRegistro);
modelo = leerCadena(fRegistro);
tipoAM = leerCadena(fRegistro);
placa = leerCadena(fRegistro); 
marca = leerCadena(fRegistro);

fRegistro.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
bRealizado = false;
}
return bRealizado;
}
```

The escribirCadena method is used on String types, because java doesnt have .writeString, heres the code for that:

```
private void escribirCadena( RandomAccessFile file, String cadena) throws IOException               
{    
StringBuffer buffer = (cadena == null)? new StringBuffer(15): 
new         StringBuffer(cadena);
buffer.setLength(30);
file.writeChars(buffer.toString());
}
```

And the leerCadena Method is for reading Strings:

```
private String leerCadena( RandomAccessFile file ) throws IOException   {
char cadena[] = new char[30], temp;
for ( int c=0;c<cadena.length;c++)
{
temp = file.readChar();
cadena[c]=temp;
}
return new String(cadena).replace('\0',' ');
}
```

I made this project based on the example of my tutor and the files are really different, heres the pic:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/63259070@N06/6449172477/in/photostream/

The one that says "Registro.txt" is my teachers and the "autosAudi.txt"  is mine

Heres one last thing: the search method kind of long:

```
public void buscar(int cod) throws IOException{
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("autosAudi.txt","rw");
boolean encontrado=false;
registroExistente = false ;
long bytes = 0;
do{
codigo = f.readInt();
costo = f.readDouble();
rendimientoGalon = f.readDouble();
ACRISS = leerCadena(f);
color = leerCadena(f);
modelo = leerCadena(f);
tipoAM = leerCadena(f);
placa = leerCadena(f);
marca = leerCadena(f);

if(cod==codigo){
iCodigoBusqueda = codigo;
encontrado=true;
registroExistente = true;
break;
}else{
iCodigoBusqueda = 0;
registroExistente = false;
}
bytes += iTamanioRegistro;
f.seek(bytes);
}
while(bytes<f.length());

if(!encontrado){
registroExistente = false;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Archivo no encontrado");
}
f.close();
}
```

**So can anyone help me out here!, it would be really great I know its kind of long but if anyone has the knowledge to solve this please share, and yes I haved tries .dat file types**

Comment: Why are you posting this without first replying to your active and similar previous question from today? The problem has already been answered. If the answer confuses you, then post a comment in your previous question and clarify your previous question. -1.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code and I'll try to point out the most obvious ones and how to fix them.

You say your RandomAccessFile does not have a way to store stings, so instead you create a StringBuffer from your String, create a String out of it and store it. You are using a method that stores strings, do not first create a StringBuffer. You also set the original capacity of the StringBuffer to 30 and seem to think that this means it will always be 30 characters. This is not so, it will only be able to store 30 characters without resizing itself.

This is causing your next problem when reading the string back. You always read 30 characters even though your string wasn't 30 characters. This gets data into your string which does not belong to it. These you then try to remove by replacing null characters with spaces.

What you want to use for storing your string is

```
RandomAccessFile.writeUTF(theString)
```

This stores the length of the string and the characters of it. For reading it back again you should use

```
RandomAccessFile.readUTF()
```

If you want to use writeChars you first need to store the length of your string so you know how many to read back when reading from the file.

This is a short example how it would work

```
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("theRandomeAccessFile", "rw");
    f.writeInt(1);
    f.writeDouble(2.34);
    f.writeUTF("SomeString");
    f.writeChar('C');
    f.seek(0);
    System.err.println(f.readInt());
    System.err.println(f.readDouble());
    System.err.println(f.readUTF());
    System.err.println(f.readChar());
```

Comment: @CesarDowns Did you try the example code I updated the answer with? Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `writeInt`, `writeDouble`, etc. methods of `RandomAccessFile` write their argument in binary form. If you want a text file, use a `FileWriter`, or an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping a `FileOutputStream` if you want to use an encoding different from the default platform encoding. Similarly, use a FileReader or an InputStreamReader wrapping a FileInputStream to read the text file.

If you want to store and read structured data from a text file, you'd better choose an easily parseable format like XML or JSON, rather than implementing your own protocol.

Regarding the bug you have, your code is too large and complex to debug it. Post a SSCCE if you want us to be able to debug.

Read the IO tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html